# JavaScript and C# date issue

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, date

I have an application which is a JavaScript (angularjs) front end with a c# Web Api back end. When hosted on our servers, all dates are fine, but when published to azure we start getting issues.
I have tried to make sure that all dates inside the c# web api are using UTC, but I am still getting issues when my interface tries to send dates to the API.

For example, I have a date selector and when a date is selected (for example the 31st Match, it looks like this in the console:

> Fri Mar 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

so when it gets to my service, that is converted to UTC which then shows it as:

> {30/03/2017 23:00:00}

This is not what I want. I want whatever date is sent from my interface to be used in my API. So if March 31st is selected, I want it to be march 31st in the API. In this case, time is not important, but I would like it to work the other way around so if the order was created at 5:15 I want my interface to show that.

I have struggled with dates for ages, they never seem to work as I expect.
If someone could explain to me how to solve this issue once and for all, that would be great.

Comment: If only the date is relevant, that's what the client should send to the server, e.g. `2017-03-31`. You may well find that if you use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library on the server, you can at least reason about things more easily.

Comment: What are you using for serializing JSON? JSON.NET or DataContractJsonSerializer  or JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: json.net is what I am using

Comment: You can trying sending in the date as string and parse it as DateTime when it hits your backend.